# How to convert RDD Structure

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

How to convert

```
RDD[(String, (((A, B), C), D))]
```

to

```
RDD[(String, (A, B, C, D))]
```

Do I need to use `flatMapValues`? I have no idea how to use it.

Can anybody help with this?

Comment: use pattern matching? `map { case (x: String , (((A,B), C),D)) => (x, (A,B,C,D)`}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `mapValues` and select the `values` from tuple as

```
rdd.mapValues(x => (x._1._1._1, x._1._1._2, x._1._2, x._2))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is almost a Scala question, more than Spark. Alternatively, try a pattern match like:

```
rdd.mapValues { case (((a, b), c), d) => (a, b, c, d) }
```

`mapValues` is important as it maintains the partitioner of the RDD, if any.